# Adding new element to Docbook

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I’m new to docbook and XSLT, I’m trying to add a new element to my docbook
I have an XML, something like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <book  version="5.0"
      xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"> 
    <d:chapter>
            <d:title/>
            <d:section>
              <d:title>Section 1</d:title>
              <d:simpara>texte   </d:simpara>
            </d:section>
          </d:chapter>
        </d:book>
```

I need to do multiples transformations in one step; First transformation is adding a new section with title and some text in the docbook xml structure then generate the transformation to get my output file as a pdf file in the second transformation.
 I create new element inside a variable, convert the variable's content to a node-set using the exlt:node-set() function, and then process the node-set with the standard DocBook stylesheets to get pdf output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
        xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
        extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
        xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
        exclude-result-prefixes="d"
        version="1.0">

    <?cco_xsltype addon="DocBook5.0" toolchain="DocBook_to_PDF_FOP"?>
    <!-- Import standard -->

    <xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/fo/profile-docbook.xsl"/>
    <!-- DocBook XSL Parameters -->

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="change"> 
        <xsl:copy>  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="change"/>  
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>         
    <xsl:template match="d:chapter" mode="change">

        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <d:section>
                <d:title> Cette section a été ajoutée </d:title>
                <d:para> ce texte a été ajouté </d:para>
            </d:section>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="d:book" >

<xsl:variable name="content"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="change"/> 
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($content)/*"  /> 

</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As result I expect a pdf file with 2 section.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a small description of what you try to achieve. What is it, that you want to see. Then maybe add how you see this as part of your DocBook xml. Now it's very hard to understand the overall goal. Too much guessing. And maybe there are other ways to resolve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to do multiples transformations in one step;
First transformation is adding a new section with title and some text in the docbook xml structure then generate the transformation to get my output file as a pdf file in the second transformation

Comment: In which environment are you operating? Are you edtiing XML and XSL files with a text editor in order to be loaded into a browser, or coding PHP at server-side, or using shell commands at the command line interface? Please specify.

Comment: i'm working with shell commands at the command line interface

Comment: Since you're using the command line, why can't you do it in two steps with a temporary intermediate file?

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure if this might answer your question. But it looks as if you want to achieve to add some standard paragraph optionally, to every document.*

If the input document contains a certain variable, it gets replaced by a standard paragraph. This paragraph is part of the XSL.

If that is indeed the case, why not **combine XML documents and fragments using XInclude**? This is a good possibility for including XML document into other XML documents. A good start is [Understanding XInclude](https://blogs.gnome.org/shaunm/2011/07/21/understanding-xinclude/).